# Maximum cover of nodes in a weighted graph with node values where the sum of edges weights and node values is less or equal to K

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a related problem or algorithm that addresses the following graph computation problem?

We have a weighted directed graph, where each node is assigned a value, and each edge has a weight. The objective is to discover a path (a list of nodes) that covers the maximum number of nodes while adhering to the following constraint: the sum of the weights of the edges connecting the nodes, plus the sum of the node values in the set, must not exceed a given constant K.

The path must be connected and node and edges can be traveled only once.

Is there a known polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, path must be connected, node and edges are traved only once

Comment: OK, then this is a variation on the Travelling Salesman Problem.  The problem in NP-hard - means that there is no polynomial time algorithm

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a known polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem ?

No.

This is a variation on the Travelling Salesman Problem ( TSP ). The problem in NP-hard - means that there is no polynomial time algorithm

---

However:

Most graph-theory algorithms are designed to look for cheapest or smallest solution.  So it would be a good idea to first transform your graph so that such algorithms can be applied - replace each weight with the maximum weight minus the original weight.

Is your transformed graph "metric"?  That is, for every possible triplet of vertices ( A,B,C ) is is ALWAYS cheaper to take the edge between two nodes rather than go via the third node.  If it is, then you can use the metric approximate solution to the TSP.  Note that most graphs that model real world problems will be metric, and the approximation is good enough for most uses.

[http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~cowen/advanced/2002/adv-lect3.pdf](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Ecowen/advanced/2002/adv-lect3.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it satisfies the Triangle inequality